# Curious problem with "Check for Broken Extensions“

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a curious problem, every time when I use "Check for Broken Extensions“, I get another result.
Sometimes it destroys the array of LocalConfiguration.php and my system crashed.

[Demo Video](https://streamable.com/mhibg)

TYPO3 9.5.5 (composer)

Installed Extension: news, ke_search, tt_address, my custom site package

Error in my LogFile:

```
Wed, 24 Apr 2019 15:10:19 +0200 [CRITICAL] request="" component="TYPO3.CMS.Core.Error.DebugExceptionHandler": Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ArrayUtility::setValueByPath() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /usr/www/users/xxxx/xxxx/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php on line 245 | TypeError thrown in file /usr/www/users/xxxx/xxxx/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/ArrayUtility.php in line 271. Requested URL: http://example.de/typo3/install.php?install[controller]=upgrade&install[context]=backend - {"TYPO3_MODE":"BE","exception":{}}
```

Does someone have an idea what it can be?